# Get URL for all tabs in browser using plugin OSX

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, plugins, safari, firebreath

I want to get all the open URLs from browsers running on the device without having to develop extensions. There are two reasons I don't want to develop extensions. First for Chrome, the user has to go to the chrome store to install the extension. Second, I have to write an extension for all browsers installed.

So I started off by looking into Scripting Bridge, but turns out it doesn't work for Chrome without GUI scripting(for which users have to enable assistive devices).

So instead, I am looking into building a plugin instead. The thing though is plugins can only support certain mime types. How do I make sure my plugin is called from any webpage? Unless there is a universal mime type which is present in all webpages, I am not sure how to solve this problem.

In any case, do you guys think this is the best way to go? Or is there any other way to get URLs of all open tabs.

Answer (score 2):

The only way to get a plugin to automatically be added to all pages would be with an extension, and there is no way without having the plugin be loaded in all pages to know about other pages other than the one that a given plugin instance is loaded in.

Plugins are not aware of the browser, only of the page they are inserted into (or loaded to handle, in the case of a plugin that handles a mimetype such as .pdf).  see http://npapi.com/extensions for more information on the capabilities of a plugin vs an extension.

Because plugins only know about a page, though, that means that they can't find out about other pages in the same browser process, including tabs. They simply don't have any method for doing this, and that is by design; the API developers didn't want anyone to be able to have a plugin that handles a media type that could somehow tie into your banking site window in another tab without you realizing it.  Of course, certain extension frameworks might allow you to find a way to do that anyway, but a plugin itself cannot.

Comment: So what do you think is the best way to approach this problem?

Comment: I don't know what your reason for wanting to do it is; honestly, my first thought is "you can't, and I'm glad you can't because I wouldn't want someone to be able to with something running on my computer" =] The closest solution I know is one you've already rejected: write an extension